# When is the sign of the potential minus and when plus?

Tags: gravity, reference-frames, potential-energy

I keep getting the sign mixed up. I tried looking online but it is just more confusing.

I know the gravitational potential energy of a body is normally of the form $$V_g = -mgz$$ where $m$ is the mass, $g$ is the gravity and $z$ is the positive (?) height from the zero potential energy.

Now, sometimes it's positive, sometimes it's negative, however it seems very arbitrary. I thought it depended on the choice of the coordinate system, but it doesn't seem so. Consider this [image: springs]

Where $z$ is the distance of the mass from the floor. Then in my book here we have $mgz$ positive!! Why is so?

Indeed in the case of a projectile thrown in air, the potential energy is negative, but the $z$ axis (or the distance from the floor) is still pointing upwards! How do I, once and for all, decide the sign of it? Having a fixed choice of axis, how do I decide $+$ or $-$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the potential energy is totally arbitrary until you define a position where the potential energy is zero when in effect you are dealing with differences in potential energy.

> $$V_g = -mgz$$ where $m$ is the mass, $g$ is the gravity and $z$ is
>   the positive (?) height from the zero potential energy.

Your confusion stems from this statement because it lacks detail.

In the diagram below I have defined a positive $z$ direction.

[image]

With the direction of $z$ increasing defined if you move a mass $m$ upwards by a distance $z$ then the change in potential energy is $(-mg)(-z) = mgz$.

This comes from the fact that an upward external force (-mg) has moved the mass upwards a distance (-z).

As expected it is an increase in potential energy but note that going up means that z becomes more negative and that is why it is minus $z$ in the evaluation of the change in potential energy.

If you want an actual value of potential energy then you must define a zero of potential energy.

If you had chosen position $C$ as your zero of potential energy then after lifting the mass up to position $A$ from position $C$ the potential energy of the mass is $(-mg)(-L) = mgL$.

On the other hand if you had chosen the zero of potential energy at  position $A$ the potential energy of the mass at position $C$, noting that to go from position $A$ to position $C$ the mass is moving in the positive z-direction, is $(-mg)(+L) = -mgL$.

The **change** in potential energy in going from position $C$ to position $A$ is the same irrespective of where the zero of potential energy was defined.

final potential energy at $A$ - initial potential energy at $C$ is equal to

$mgL - 0 = 0 -(-mgL) = mgL$

---

You could have chosen the positive z-direction as upwards and used as the change in potential energy $mgz$ noting that to lift the mass up the external force is in the positive z-direction.

[image]

If you had chosen position $C$ as your zero of potential energy then after lifting the mass up to position $A$ from position $C$, the potential energy of the mass is $(+mg)(+L) = mgL$, the same as before.

On the other hand if you had chosen the zero of potential energy at  position $A$ the potential energy of the mass at position $C$ is $(+mg)(-L) = -mgL$, again the same as before.

---

So the advice is, define a positive direction and if you want to find the potential energy define a position where the potential energy is zero.

Answer (score 1):

This all depends on the reference point. The point at which you define the zero of potential energy to be will determine the sign.

In your diagram I suggest that you provide the reference to the book source showing how it arrived at $mgz$ as with a two spring system we require the use of Hooke's law. The springs elasticity need to be stated.